# Unknown coded segment appearing in Gödel, Escher, Bach

Tags: cipher

> [image]
>
> Copyright © 1979 by Basic Books, inc.

This segment appears on page 18 in *Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid, first ed.* (without any further instruction about what it might be). Does anybody here have any idea on what it is and/or what it conveys?

Comment: Looks like it might be simple sub. Too short really to do effective frequency analysis though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translated to Hebrew characters:

> בראשית ברא אלהים ויאמר אלהים יהי אור ויאמר אלהים יהי רקיע ויאמר אלהים יקוו המים ויאמר אלהים תדשא

Which roughly translates to:

> In the beginning god created and god said let there be light and god said let there be sky and god said let there be vegetation

Answer (score 5):

It’s mentioned on page 14:

> Facing Words of Thanks: The beginning of Genesis, in ancient Hebrew (xviii)

<s>As @BeastyGerbil notes, it’s probably a substitution cipher. The Shin (fourth letter on the first line, starting from the right) is recognizable, but the others not so much. Unless it’s a script I’m not familiar with?</s>

It seems to be written in the [Samaritan alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-Hebrew_alphabet#Letters) (note: those letters don't render in Firefox for me, but they do in Safari), which is different from the present Hebrew alphabet I'm familiar with.